# How are numbers encoded in unicode with right-to-left languages? (Normalisation)

Tags: unicode, encoding, arabic, right-to-left, lemmatization

During an Information Retrieval lecture, there were slides talking about the lemmatisation and/or normalisation of tokens for indexing and querying text documents. One of those mentioned right-to-left languages such as Arabic, but in unicode they're encoded logically/sequentially in the same manner as left-to-right languages, just displayed right-to-left. This makes sense, but how are numbers encoded (in particular those using Roman Numerals)?

[image: Aracbic Script and Bidirectionality Lecture Slide]

In the English, the year "1962" would have the characters encoded sequentially as `1962` with unicode and most other character encodings. However, in Arabic, it's unclear whether the year "1962" as shown in the lecture slide would be encoded sequentially as `1962` and then rendered left-to-right (so the [document is technically bidirectional](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bi-directional_text#Unicode_bidi_support)), or encoded as `2691` and rendered right-to-left as the text would be.

This matters for indexing so that the year 1962 in Arabic and English texts are both the same token in an index. Do I need to reverse the characters from in the Arabic language to normalise them, or are they encoded in the same order as English?

Comment: I don't think you need to reverse the numbers, I think this has already been considered by the encoding methods since even the Arabic numbers are written from left to right as the Roman numbers.

Comment: Reading order only affects the text renderer, not the encoding.

Comment: The numbers may be written left-to-right, but if they're encoded left-to-right while the rest of the document is encoded right-to-left I'd imagine that leads to a much bigger headache for rendering algorithms?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I found the answer with [Unicode Bi-Directional Text](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bi-directional_text#Unicode_bidi_support). Unicode is meant to be encoded *logically* as opposed to the order it's rendered in, thereby the rendering algorithm can still perform line breaks correctly for different paragraph widths (and also explains why right-to-left support sometimes needs to be explicitly enabled, since it's more complex to render).

From wikipedia, it appears that unicode groups characters into four types of "orders": strong, weak, neutral, and explicit. Numbers fall under the weak ordering as they have a vague directionality. From wikipedia:

> Unless a directional override is present numbers are always encoded (and entered) big-endian, and the numerals rendered LTR. The weak directionality only applies to the placement of the number in its entirety. [(1)](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr9/#Resolving_Weak_Types)

Therefore as far as I understand, the number "1962" should be encoded in the same logical order (`1962`) in a typical left-to-right string as it would be in a string with right-to-left characters.